# How to select decrypt() from table in laravel + postgres

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I want to get an encrypted field from a postgre database to be decrypted using select decrypt() in pgsql

I have try

```
$name = DB::connection('jb_system')->select("select decrypt(name, 'key', 'aes') as names from employee");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm use encode inside the raw

```
 $name = DB::connection('conn_name')->table('employee')->select(DB::connection('conn_name')->raw("encode(decrypt(name, 'key', 'aes'), 'escape')"))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DB::raw`

```
$name = DB::connection('jb_system')->table("employee")
        ->select(DB::raw("decrypt(name, 'key', 'aes') as names"))
        ->get();
```

Comment: I got stream resource @241 when i use dd function to see the response

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but i had got the answer.